Value edition of tables in Quarto workbook
I have a Quarto workbook that needs to present a table and i need that the values are able to be changed by the user (and saved back to the table).
The usual process is to read (using R) a file (typically a parquet... or from Duckdb, which is simple). Them I need to present it with some framework that allows edition. This is really tricky.
I think my best option now is to use Observable JS (in Quarto) and try to use DataTables but:

I still haven't found any one that could smoothly import DataTables into OJS cell in Quarto.
(As consequence) don't know if edition is possible.
The last step (saving back to file in this approach) is a complete open question for me.

Can you, please, let me know if I'm in the right direction? Any other ideas that I should explore?
